# How to store date in ldap?

Tags: ldap

How can we store date in ldap?? Is there any attribute defined for storing date ??Or Is there any way we can create certain attributes according to need ...I am storing the fields programatically using java and spring .

Answer (score 2):

Are you aiming to store date+time or a sole date?

If you have both date and time, you should use the standard [Generalized Time](http://tools.ietf.org//html/rfc4517#section-3.3.13) syntax. However, it is only suitable for storing date and time with at least one hour precision. If you know the date only,

If you have a date with no time, you need to use a custom format to store it. You can look at a relevant discussion on [how to store birthday in LDAP](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mozilla.dev.tech.ldap/Ast6WzQbgsQ/discussion). As you can find there, there's no single solution and various software is using various approaches to store the date.

Of the various solutions used, in my opinion two are of particular interest. One is to use `YYYYMMDD` format — which is basically Generalized Time stripped to the day. The other is to use a more readable `YYYY-MM-DD` as specified by [ISO8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm).

Using them will either require defining a new syntax in the schema, or using a broader type ([Numeric String](http://tools.ietf.org//html/rfc4517#section-3.3.23) for the former, [IA5 String](http://tools.ietf.org//html/rfc4517#section-3.3.15) for the latter).

Answer (score 0):

Define an attribute in the schema using the [Generalized Time](http://tools.ietf.org//html/rfc4517#section-3.3.13) syntax and use that attribute for storing dates, times, etc.